# Showing different price on category page and single product page in variable product in bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Showing different price on category page and single product page in variable product in bigcommerce. I just want to show the lowest price on category page.
This is the category page: https://hilineelectronics.com/portable-audio/. In the first product price is showing $112.99 and after checking it quick view and single product page it is showing $83.99. I want $83.99 (varibale amount) amount there.
How can we do this? Any variable or code for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean to say that the price should be same in category or single page ?

Comment: Yes, price should be same on both pages. You can check the links.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your CategoryProductsItem.html  check the code

```
<em class="p-price">%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%</em>
```

Is there %%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%% call same or different with product details page.
ProductDetails.html

```
<span class="ProductPrice VariationProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%</span>
```

Compare both files global varriable.

The second way makes the backup and of the files and then revert it to the original.

Comment: %%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%% variable is already there. Same variable on both pages ProductDetails.html and CategoryProductListsItem.html but output is different.

Comment: can you send me the screenshot of your admin end where you adding products different prices